# How could I purge or merge milions of files in HDFS?

Tags: linux, hadoop

In our Datalake (Hadoop/Mapr/Redhat) we have a directory which contains more than 40M of files. We can't run a ls command.

I've tried to launch hadoop command  getmerge to merge the files, but I have no output.

Hadoop fs -rm don't work too .

Is there another way to view the contenent of this folder ? How could I purge old files from it without a scan ?

Thank you

Comment: I think `hadoop fs -rm` works, but it will require such a long time to delete 40M files that it appears not to do anything.

Comment: Hello , unfortunatly, it does'nt work ... I let it for the whole night without removing one file :(  I'm looking for another way !

Comment: Silly question, but how do you know it didn't remove a single file if you can't do an `ls`?

Comment: Having been through the aftermath of somebody running a script with a poorly placed space, `fs -rm -R` will quite exuberantly delete, or move to trash, whatever you point it at regardless of size.  In my old team's case, `/`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.  If you have access to the namenode or secondary you can use the `hdfs oiv` to dump the HDFS to an offline delimited file then find the paths you're looking for there.

Hadoop has an existing file format called `.har` which stands for Hadoop archive.  If you want to preserve your files you should look into using that instead of `getmerge`.

You can use `distcp` to delete directories.

You can create an empty HDFS directory in /tmp and then copy the empty directory into your directory with 40M files using `distcp` and do the remove with more mappers.

```
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/empty_dir
$ hadoop distcp -m 20 -delete /tmp/empty_dir /PATH-OF-MILLION-FILES-DIR
```

The `fs -rm -r` is single-threaded while `distcp` runs in parallel based on mappers.  You should use the `-delete` option with `distcp`.

References:

- [Offline Image Viewer Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html)
- [Hadoop Archives Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-archives/HadoopArchives.html)
- [DistCp Version2 Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html)

Comment: `distcp -delete` will remove the files in the destination, if they exist, I thought.

Comment: Yeah, this was hack I found to delete a directory with lots of entries.  I don't know at what point you saturate your NN though.

Comment: My point was you say "you can use `distcp` to delete", which I don't think is true. The documentation states "Delete the files existing in the dst but **not in src**", unless you are saying to copy or move to /tmp, and **then** use distcp, at which point, you still get the original data in the same location

Comment: If src is an empty directory, and I copy an empty directory to a full one, the effect is the same as `rm -r` but with better parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

`fs -rm` will move to HDFS trash, so you're not actually deleting any records, just moving them.

You need to add `-skipTrash` for a purge to happen. And if would recommend that you purge in batches

For example, remove all files starting with letter `a`

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R -skipTrash /path/data/a*
```

'getmerge` downloads all records to your local machine, so you better be sure you have enough disk space

The only way to merge within HDFS is a MapReduce or Spark task.

It depends on your file formats, but FileCrush is a library you could look into. However, keep in mind that if you want to merge anything, you need at least 120% extra capacity on HDFS to duplicate the data + overhead for temporary files

Comment: Thanks for those informations. 

Unfortunatly, launching "hdfs dfs -rm -R -skipTrash /a/b*" don't work too , still waiting from the morning without any result or information displayed !

FileCrush does'nt work too for me .. but I'm still looking for a way to do it . Don't hesitate if you have other ways to manage that :)